# Magento store has multi store view, full site and mobile, but isn't loading the default

Tags: redirect, mobile

Before, I had only one store view which is the full site view, and by adding exceptions at the store design, I can show mobile users a different theme. But this way, I can not redirect the users to full site.

So I did some online search, and some people say to create a new store view for mobile, and assign mobile theme for this store view. Then use url `?__store=mobile` and `?__store=default` to switch between mobile and full site.

But during the process, my problem is, after I create a new store view and assign mobile theme to it, and I type the site url it uses mobile theme by default! And I double checked that I set the full site store view as default.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: It may help to include some code - I'm personally unfamiliar with Magento, but surely there is a configuration file of which you could post some relevant section?

Comment: I have not got to the code right now, I just created a new store view and assign a theme, then by default store view's theme changed too.